# Does Shaitan (Satan) entice Non Muslims?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shaitan

It is confirmed that Shaitan dissuades Muslim into doing wrong things. Does Satan entice non Muslims also into doing wrong things, if yes in what way? Also does Satan entice Christians and Jews also who are the people of the book.

What is Islamic ruling on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

Shaitan is not the enemy of just Muslims. It is the enemy of the whole mankind.

> #### [Al-Baqarah :: Ayah 168](http://quran.com/2/168)
>
> O mankind, eat from whatever is on earth [that is] lawful and good and do not follow the footsteps of Satan. Indeed, he is to you a clear enemy.
>
> ---
>
> #### [Yūsuf :: Ayah 5](http://quran.com/12/5)
>
> ....Indeed Satan, to man, is a manifest enemy.

Shaitan misguides the whole mankind in the ways very similar to how it misguides the Muslims: by dragging them both away from the truth (Islam)...

> #### [Al-'A`rāf :: Ayah 16](http://quran.com/7/16)
>
> [Satan] said, "Because You have put me in error, I will surely sit in wait for them on Your straight path.

...and by making the wrong things attractive to them.

> #### [An-Nisā' :: Ayah 120](http://quran.com/4/120)
>
> Satan promises them and arouses desire in them. But Satan does not promise them except delusion.

But it is of course more easy for Shaitan to misguide Non-muslims and the weaker Muslims.

> #### [An-Naĥl :: Ayah 100](http://quran.com/16/100)
>
> His power is only over those who obey and follow him (Satan), and those who join partners with Him (Allah) [i.e. those who are Mushrikun - polytheists.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Answer (score 2):

Satan is an enemy to all mankind, not just to Muslims:

> [Iblees] said, "Do You see this one [Adam] whom You have honored above me? If You delay me until the Day of Resurrection, **I will surely destroy his descendants, except for a few.**"
>   <sup>[[Al-'Isra' 62](http://quran.com/17/62)]</sup>

God commands all the children of Adam to [guard themselves against the temptations of Satan](http://quran.com/7/27).  Satan tempts people away from God by innumerable means, and there's no reason to believe that his methodology is somehow different for Muslims, or Jews, or Christians, or non-believers.