# How does Shaitan travel around the world?

Tags: shaitan, jinn

I need to be careful to avoid [Shaitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_(Islam)) deterring me from the straight path.  Simultaneously, [so does everyone else](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8131/17163)... everywhere.  That's a lot of travelling for Shaitan.  Presumably, Shaitan doesn't fly from country to country (racking up frequent flyer miles), but has some other mechanism for travelling.

**Question**: How does Shaitan travel around the world?

I'm getting the feeling I'm misunderstanding something here.  Can Shaitan be in multiple places at once?

Comment: There are lesser shaitan called shayateen and of course there's human devils. There are times like Ramadan when he's locked up even then people misbehave!

Comment: I fear there is mocking tone about travelling of satan. Travel of satan is from revelation. When an individual uses frequent flier miles I feel there is ridicule of revelation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leader of devils, ibleez has a huge army.

> “Verily, he and Qabiluhu (his soldiers from the jinn or his tribe) see you from where you cannot see them” (Quran, Surah Al-Aaraf: 27).

Shayateen (evil among jinns) and jinns differ from humans in travel time taken. They can cover huge distances in a short span of time.

> An Ifrit (strong) from the jinns said: "I will bring it to you before you rise from your place (council). And verily, I am indeed strong, and trustworthy for such work." (An-Naml 27:39)

The above verse makes it clear that jinn can traverse long distances in a short span.

Another proof from revelation is Jinns can reach lowest heaven quickly and steal minor information from angels. Lowest heaven is at a distance of 500 years.

Jinns are not given control over riding beasts and ocean going vessels by Allah. (Will add references)

Comment: Does this mean that when Shaytan is mentioned in the Quran, it is not necessarily Iblees? For instance the verse: "إِنَّمَا ذَٰلِكُمُ الشَّيْطَانُ يُخَوِّفُ أَوْلِيَاءَهُ" (3:175) it is mentioned in [tafsir zamakshari](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/3/al-imran/175/al-zamakhshari): "والمراد بالشيطان نعيم، أو أبو سفيان. ويجوز أن يكون على تقدير حذف المضاف، بمعنى إنما ذلكم قول الشيطان، أي قول إبليس لعنه الله"